# Convert Access table to SharePoint list with auto increment ID starting from the same number

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I need to move a table from within an ms access database to a SharePoint list. The table I need to move has had old records removed that has ID's auto increment. I need the SharePoint list to start from the same auto increment number as in the table.

I have tried using the ms access export to SharePoint list functionality but when I re-import the table back into access as a linked table to a SharePoint list the ID has started back at 1 (not 81 like in the table I uploaded to SharePoint).

I need the table to upload to the SharePoint list with the auto increment ID starting at 81 as it is in the table initially.

Answer (score 2):

I understand Albert's logic, but somewhat disagree.  I worked with one client that had been using an original Auto-numbered field as the Customer's ID in their access database for years, so their work orders, invoices, etc..., all have the Customer's ID there.  If you use the newly-created autonumber field, then all customer id's would change to new numbers.  Worse yet, if you use a 2nd, non-autonumber field as Albert recommends, then anytime you add a new customer, you would need to use a sql statement (or query) to determine the last used number from this 2nd field and increment it 1 so that it is unique.  Kind of a pain.

So, the workaround is still a pain, but for a solution that does what you actually asked, you can do this.  Create a new list in SharePoint with an auto-numbered field.  link that list in the access database.  then, look at the highest ID number (eg highest customer id) from the table with your original data... because you need to create that many rows in the SharePoint list.  You can either create code to loop through creating x number of records, or if you're not comfortable with that, create an excel sheet with that many rows.  then, import that excel file into the linked table.  next, create a delete query which deletes all records in the linked table that doesn't have the matching ID (eg customer ID) in your access table.  this leaves you with a linked list with only the IDs you are using, and it's still auto-numbering so new records are automatically assigned new numbers.

Like I said, it's a bit of a work-around.  But this actually does what you are asking for, instead of being forced into a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the column in question is a autonumber column, then during a upload or migration then those autonumbers can change. Since such numbers have NO meaning, then this should not matter. If you have several related tables then you MUST ensure that your relations are setup correctly before you move the data to sharepoint (because SharePooint will re-number these values, then the child tables and FK keys ALSO will be correctly updated). However, if you don't set the relationships, then you WILL break the related data since SharePoint does and can and will re-number the PK's used.

You are limited to ONLY using autonumber PK's if you wish to keep related tables intact. You cannot control this re-numbering, but as noted the number ONE rule in databases is that such numbers do NOT matter anyway.

If you MUST and WANT to stop the re-numbering of that column, then change the data type to a long number, and NOT  autonumber type. And then of course simply add another autonumber column. So to STOP or PREVENT the numbers being changed, you have to convert the column from being autonumber to a standard long number column. (edit: you ALSO thus have to ensure that the column is NOT marked as PK).

Keep in mind that any other table as part of the related data will ALSO see those standard long number columns re-numbered and changed if that column is part of a defined relationships to some PK. So Access during a up-size WILL re-number the PK (autonumber) and will ALSO automatic for you re-number the FK columns used in child tables. If you as noted do NOT want such re-numbering to occur, then the PK and FK columns can NOT be part of a defined relationship.

So dropping the autonumber column is the only way to prevent such re-numbering. Since autonumbers don't have any real meaning, then if they are changed during a up-load, then this should not matter.